# Exchanging limits and integrals

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $\{f_i\}$ be a sequence of pointwise discontinuous functions whose limit is Dirichlet's function. I read that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n(x)dx \not= \int \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)dx$$

as the right hand side attempts to integrate Dirichlet's function, which is not (Riemann) integrable. I get that part.

I don't really understand why the left hand makes sense though. I see that for any finite $i$, $f_i$ it is discontinuous on a non-dense set, so it's integrable, but when $i$ goes to infinity it seems to me like this integral shouldn't exist.

I guess one confusion is it seems like $\frac{d}{dx}(\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n(x)dx)$ should equal $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ which I suppose can't be true, but it doesn't seem obvious why.

Comment: Take a look at the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)

Comment: @Patrick: Not sure I understand. I get that they may be Lebesgue integrable; I just don't understand why it's not Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, what you read talks about sequences of function like
$$
f_n:x\in [0, 1]\to 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text {if $x = r_i$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\{r_n\}_1^\infty$ is a sequence of all rational numbers belonging to the interval $[0, 1]$.

Each function $f_n$ is Riemann integrable and
$$
\int_0^1 f_n(t)dt = 0
$$
therefore the limit on the left side exists and is $0$.

Comment: Yes, this is the example. But by the fundamental theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n(t)dt = \lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(b)-F_n(a)$ - it seems like if this $F$ exists, its derivative should be dirichlet's function.